# angular 2 - how to inject css for third party library

Tags: angular

I have a third party lib in my project, it's like this

```
import ng2-datepicker from 'ng2-datepicker'

    @Component({
        selector: 'CreateEvent',
        template: `
            <form>
                <ng2-datepicker formControlName="startDate"></ng2-datepicker>
                <input />
            </form>
        `,
        styleUrls: ['./ngdatepicker.scss'],
    })
```

problem:  doesn't have any style.

If I include the ngdatepicker.scss in the global style.scss, then  receives it's style. But that's kind of hacky. Is there way to inject ngdatepicker.scss into ?